Exception encountered when calling BroadcastTo.call()
I'm trying to train a text sequence prediction model from image (LSTM + CNN). However, When I try to train a model it results in BroadcastTo error in the internal layer which is difficult to debug further.
Error message is:
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-01c02dee08c0> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()
      4 
----> 5 model.fit([train_images, train_sequences], train_sequences,
      6           epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120             # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121             # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123         finally:
    124             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    611       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    612     except TypeError:
--> 613       raise TypeError(f"Failed to convert elements of {values} to Tensor. "
    614                       "Consider casting elements to a supported type. See "
    615                       "https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes "

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling BroadcastTo.call().

Failed to convert elements of (None, 100, 256) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.

Arguments received by BroadcastTo.call():
  • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 100, 1), dtype=bool)

Model Code
IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT = 200, 50
EMBEDDING_DIM = 256
MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 100  # Max length of output sequence

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class CastingLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CastingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.cast(inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

def create_cnn_encoder():
    """Create the CNN feature extractor."""
    inputs = Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1))  # Grayscale input
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    cnn_output = Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM, activation='relu')(x)
    return Model(inputs, cnn_output)

def create_model():
    """Create the encoder-decoder model."""
    cnn_encoder = create_cnn_encoder()

    # Encoder
    encoder_input = cnn_encoder.input
    encoder_output = cnn_encoder.output
    encoder_output = RepeatVector(MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, name='enc_output')(encoder_output)

    # Decoder
    decoder_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,))
    decoder_embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, mask_zero=True)(decoder_input) 

    #decoder_gru = Bidirectional(GRU(256, return_sequences=True), name='dec_gru')(decoder_embedding)
    decoder_gru = GRU(256, return_sequences=True, name='gru')(decoder_embedding)
    decoder_gru = TimeDistributed(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM), name='td_gru')(decoder_gru) # Added a Dense layer to match encoder output dimension

    # Concatenate Encoder and Decoder
    decoder_concat = Concatenate()([encoder_output, decoder_gru])
    # Modified: Wrap the Dense layer in a lambda layer to handle the mask
    dense_layer = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax') 
    decoder_output = TimeDistributed(dense_layer)(decoder_concat)

    # Full Model
    model = Model([encoder_input, decoder_input], decoder_output)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()

The model image is:
I have tried the following:

Manually cast the input to float (from images) and int32 (from sequences)
Have tried to add casting layer after decoding layer. it is not possible due-to masking in decoding layer, which is not supported (later layers are expected for follow the masking)
I have tried to follow trace callback, but they are masked. I have tried to disable internal filtering. There is no change in the output trace.

Expectation is that model training should work as the input layers are of float32 and int32.
